# Silverlight: Modal ChildWindow keeps parent grayed after closing

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

When my modal ChildWindow closes, the parent control does not get "un-grayed" and all user input is blocked, forcing me to restart the application. Exact scenario which causes this behavior consistently:

1. ChildWindow A pops up and user clicks a custom button on the bottom of the window (instead of OK or Cancel). My code does some work and then calls the Close() method for the ChildWindow.
2. ChildWindow A closes and functionality is restored to parent control (controls are un-grayed).
3. User causes ChildWindow B to pop up. User clicks system-generated OK or Cancel button.
4. ChildWindow B closes, but the parent controls are still grayed out and inaccessible.

Either of the windows work fine repeatedly on their own. Any thoughts?

Comment: Unable reproduce.  Perhaps there is a problem in "My code does some work"?

Comment: This happened to me some time ago. In my case I was opening the second ChildWindow at the same time I was closing the first one. Solved by giving the first ChildWindow a time to close.

Answer (score 7):

I saw something similar (it might not fix your exact problem) and found some discussion about the ChildWindow [here](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/t/176423.aspx)

they suggested this method in the ChildWindow Closed event and it worked for me.

```
Application.Current.RootVisual.SetValue(Control.IsEnabledProperty, true);
```

Also try calling this.DialogResult = true instead of the Close method.

Comment: This line actually works for me:

Application.Current.RootVisual.SetValue(Control.IsEnabledProperty, true);